# Process network activity monitoring

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to monitor incoming connections for processing.
I tried `GetExtendedTCPTable` (UDP too), but some connections that are listed by perfmon.exe (Perfomance Monitor), are not displayed in my app.
Can anyone explain why this happens and how to monitor all network activity for a process.
I need: `RemoteIP`, `LocalPort`.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please post the code you have written so we can see what you have done so far and can help you from there.

Comment: also sould be helpful if you can let know what is working and what i s not.. like tcp is working but udp you are not getting etc.. Also did you check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573504/getextendedtcptable-donesnt-return-the-same-result-as-netstat-ano

Comment: yeah i tried all of this.
Working: TCP works, UDP too. BUT.
When i check permon, i see additional connections, i assume this is incomming connections to open UDP port. And those connections doesn't appear in extended tables.
Also i've finished an solution by using sniffer and filtering it's information by PID opened ports. afterwards i'm adding ip 1 by 1 to another table with no duplication of IP addresses, so at finis i've got tables of IP connected to PID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found.
[MJSNiffer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17031/A-Network-Sniffer-in-C) can help you with. You can get PID opened ports, and track all connections to exacts ports by filtering Sniffered data.